# Structured data file reader class

Tags: java, io

Is there any class provided in the Java standard API that allows file structure elements to be described, like headers and records, according to the data types that are found in those elements, and automatically read them in? I have a feeling I'm going to be writing my own class for this... but I would like to do something like so:

```
// PSEUDO CODE
header.setStructure("integer:tag:0x4F3C", "integer:version", "integer:numrecords");
record.setStructure("integer:numpoints", "integers:point:var->numpoints");
myHeader = file.read(header);
myRecord = file.read(record);
```

Comment: You'll be writing your own class(es), but there are a number of ways to make that easier. Consider exploring a file structure DSL in Groovy/JRuby/etc., of which I've seen a few, although they're relatively easy to write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there isn't.
But you can use XML, JSON or CSV to store your data in files.

To manipulate XML you can use DOM or SAX which are in the standard libraries.
For the others there are libraries.

---

For reading easily binary data you can use [`ByteBuffer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html).
If you have a composite type, you can create a class or a static method that reads it from a buffer.

Comment: Thanks. I know about XML, but I need a class that reads existing binary types that do not conform to XML or other types of generic structures. I'm trying to port my shapefile reading class to Java, and I figured a set of classes like this would improve readability bigtime.